# mounting USB volume in docker

Tags: docker

I have a USB volume connected to debian host. I would like "mount" the device inside docker. Using --volume is not possible, as the device may be ephemeral and even container is also not running.

Workflow will look something like:

- container will startup (will have access to only USB devices it needs to access)
- mount volume  inside
- do some work
- unmount
- stop the container

This is not working for me (/dev/sdc is my usb device. ideally I want to use /dev/disk/by-id/usb-MBED_VFS_0240000048824e450041700fdedd003598d1000097969900-0:0 but --device doesn't take : in it's path)

```
vagrant@parallels:~$ sudo docker run --rm --interactive --tty --device /dev/sdc ubuntu
    [sudo] password for vagrant:
    root@76c5c87bd4a6:/# mkdir /tmp/1
    root@76c5c87bd4a6:/# mount /dev/sdc /tmp/1
    mount: /tmp/1: permission denied.
```

It works if --privileged is passed

```
vagrant@parallels:~$ sudo docker run --rm --interactive --tty --privileged --device /dev/sdc ubuntu
root@1717829c3d16:/# mkdir /tmp/1
root@1717829c3d16:/# mount /dev/sdc /tmp/1
root@1717829c3d16:/# ls /tmp/1
```

**Why do I need to pass --privileged even if I use "--device"**

Answer (score 0):

Passing `--device` gives you access to the device, but does not grant you permissions to modify the filesystem via a `mount` operation. That is, the "permission denied" error comes from a `mount` attempt, not from an attempt to access the device.

Note that an alternate workflow would be to mount the device on your host into a temporary directory and then star the container with a bind mount (`-v /temporary/mountpoint:/path/in/container`). This has the advantage of requiring neither `--device` nor elevated privileges.